# Why is 'this' in a Meteor Template onRendered Function undefined?

Tags: meteor, this

I'm using meteor 0.6.4. The problem i have is that the data context when rendering a template is sometimes undefined, so that, 'this' object is a reference to Window:

```
Template.task.time_left = function(){
    debugger;
    var nDate = this.due_date.getTime();

Exception from Deps recompute: TypeError: Cannot call method 'getTime' of undefined
```

The html code is wrapped inside an {{each}} handlebars statement:

```
<template name="tasks_lists">
    {{#each tasks_list}}
    ...
        {{#each task}}
            {{> task}}
        {{/each}}
    ...
    {{/each}}
</template>
<template name="task">
...
    <div class="text">{{due_date}}</div>
...
</template>
```

I read that this bug was solved in an earlier version of Meteor. What can I do to aviod the function being called with 'this' as Window.

Answer (score 0):

You should use template.xxx.helpers instead, ie:

```
Template.task.helpers({
  nDate: function() {
    return this.due_date.getTime();
  }
});
```

When you use it within helpers, this is the data context.

Answer (score 0):

I used 'helpers' function and I have the same problem. 'this' object is sometimes the window object:

```
Template.task.helpers({
...
    'time_left': function(){
        debugger;
        var nDate = this.due_date.getTime();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

When using any of the three Meteor template callback functions, including the `onRendered` function, the `this` object is actually a template instance object. Although it is possible to retrieve the data context of the template through this object, it is recommended that you reference the template data context through the use of the `Template.currentData()` function. The documentation for this function can be found [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_currentdata).

Answer (score -1):

The `this` inside a template helper will always points to `window` object.

You can access the `data` context in `Template.rendered()` or the event handler function. In the event handlers, it is passed as a second argument as `function( event, template )`, where the `template` is the current template object.

However I suggest you to use the template instance functions such as `find(), findAll(), firstNode(), lastNode()` rather than data context.

```
Template.task.rendered = function() {
   if( !this.window ){     //check that 'this' is not a 'window' object
      var el = this.find( 'div.text' );  // the div that holds due_date
      //do something 
   }
}
```

Comment: The `this` object inside of a template `onRendered` callback function is a reference to the template instance associated with the function. See the [Meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) for more details on the `onRendered` template callback function.